# IE Issue: Unwanted Small Vertical Gap

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am having an issue with my fathers website.(http://arcwebsolutions.net/arcmktg) Everything works perfectly in Firefox and Chrome. But in Internet Explorer(So far I have tested it in IE 7-9) it is displaying a *small* 2-3px gap at the right end of my nav menu, also if you look closely there is a small indent on the left side of my footer. I am using a 960px fixed width website layout that I have designed myself, but for the life of me I cannot figure out the issue.

Here's the html

```
<div id="menu" class="width">
<ul>
<li>
<a href="index.html">
<span class="title ">Home</span></a>      
</li>
<li>
<a href="philosophy.html">
<span class="title ">Car Magnets</span></a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="services.html">
<span class="title ">Free Virtual Magnet</span></a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="portfolio.php">
<span class="title ">Custom T-Shirts</span></a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="contact.html">
<span class="title ">Silicone Wristbands</span></a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Here is the css for the menu

```
#menu {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#menu ul {
   width: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  background: url(images/navbg.gif);
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;

}

#menu ul li {
   display: inline;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   list-style: none;
}

#menu ul li a {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: "Avant Garde", Avantgarde, "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, "AppleGothic", sans-serif;
  color: #666666;
}

#menu ul li a span {
  display: block;
  padding: 6px 1px;
}


#menu ul li a:hover,
#menu ul li a.here {
  color: #000;
  background: url(images/hover.gif);
}
```

please visit http://arcwebsolutions.net/arcmktg to see what I am talking about. Could it be a doctype issue? Or a coding error? Either way, I cannot seem to find it.

Comment: You'll get better help if you supply the CSS and HTML of the area the problem exists in. Also, a screen shot of the issue in IE. People will be less inclined to fire up IE just to check your site.

Comment: Can you make screenshot, I don't see any difference in IE9.  Since it is a minute a screenshot with marker will be great.  Also @Michael said, add the respective css here.

Comment: s/he is the first user, so he cannot place any screen shot here.

Comment: @C-Link But OP can provide a link of the screenshot here.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. But it may also be okay if s/he provide key html and css code here.

Comment: Sorry guys, I have added the area of html and css where the direct problem lies, but I feel that the issue is somewhere else within my code.

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the main area of focus. This was taken on IE9

http://arcwebsolutions.net/ieissue.jpg

I understand this my look like nothing, but it bugs the ^*(& out of me. I have found that not all IE displays this gap.... IE9 on my laptop displays correctly, while IE9 on my desktop does not...

Comment: Can you try to remove the line break between the <a> and the <span> Tag?

Comment: I don't have any solution, but I must congratulate you on actually using `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/xhtml+xml; ...` for your XHTML. One doesn't see that very often.

Comment: Stefan, thanks I just tried that, still have the gap though.

Thanks Mr Lister!